# Linear Algebra Vector Space Inquiry

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[Tried 1 way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fntf.png)

[Tried 2nd way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9prZl.png)

Both ways don't seem to work. 
The answers mentioned are not right. 
What is the right answer then?
Please advise.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange! It is very hard to understand what you are asking, you don't even state the question itself inside the post. Please try to provide all details inside the post and not link to screenshots.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you please format your question in a clear manner?

Comment: Use the definition of linear independence!!!

Answer (score 0):

Form a matrix whose rows are the given vectors (polynomials)'s coefficients and reduce it (by rows, of course) modulo $\;3\;$:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&0\\
1&1&2\\
0&2&2\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2-R_1}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&0\\
0&2&2\\
0&2&2\end{pmatrix}$$

and now we can see at once that vectors $\;2,\,3\;$ are linearly dependent, and we find at once a relation of dependency by the above:

$$0=R_3-R_2'=R_3-(R_2-R_1)\implies R_1+2R_2+R_3=0$$

(the comma in $\;R_2'\;$ denotes the row we got after the first and unique operation shown above)

with $\;R_1=1+2x\,,\,\,R_2=1+x+2x^2\,,\,\,R_3=2x+2x^2\;$